# Finding a Regular Grammar

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, context-free-grammar

so I have to find a regular grammar to generate the following sets:

$(1)$ $\{aa, ab, ac\}$
$(2)$ $\{ab^n,ba^n\mid n\ge 0\}$
$(3)$ $\{ab^{2n}\mid n\ge0\}$

I'm wondering if anyone can check my work and let me know if I'm correct. If not, any help/assistance would greatly be appreciated!

---

$(1)$
$$\begin{align*}
&S\to A\\
&A\to aa\\
&A\to ab\\
&A\to ac
\end{align*}$$

Is this correct for $(1)$? Do I need $A\to\lambda$?

**Edit:** Is another alternative/correct/better/worse solution:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to A\\
&A\to aB\\
&B\to a\\
&B\to b\\
&B\to c
\end{align*}$$

---

$(2)$

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to AB\\
&S\to BA\\
&A\to aA\mid a\\
&B\to bB\mid b
\end{align*}$$

---

$(3)$

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to AB\\
&A\to a\\
&B\to bB\mid b
\end{align*}$$

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @hardmath I already used it, post looks fine to me. Thank you for your useless input.

Comment: I’ve corrected your MathJax and added MathJax where you didn’t bother. If you plan to ask questions here in the future, you really should spend some time learning how to use it properly; you’ll find information [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I’m pretty easy-going, but a lot of regulars will downvote your questions if you don’t use it. And even I will say that *fine* is a bit of an exaggeration when you still had things like `n >= 0`.

Comment: I literally just joined this forum and made my first post, sorry for being the slightest of improper in the first attempt.

Comment: I’m not criticizing what you did with the question; as I say, I’m pretty easy-going on that score. I don’t expect newcomers to be expert at formatting, and in any case I had no trouble reading it. I also don’t really mind taking the trouble to improve its looks. I *was* criticizing the snippiness of your response to the previous commenter, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first grammar does generate the language $\{aa,ab,ac\}$, but whether it is regular depends on exactly what definition of *regular grammar* you have. By [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), for instance, it is not regular, because none of your productions is allowed in either a right regular or a left regular grammar. Your second grammar for that language, however, *is* regular (specifically, right regular).

Your grammar for $(2)$ is not regular, thanks to the first two productions, and it does not generate the right language. It allows the derivation

$$S\Rightarrow AB\Rightarrow aAB\Rightarrow aaB\Rightarrow aabB\Rightarrow aabb\;,$$

even though $aabb$ is not in the language. Try this instead:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aB\mid bA\mid a\mid b\\
&A\to aA\mid a\\
&B\to bB\mid b
\end{align*}$$

The production $S\to AB$ in your grammar for $(3)$ is again problematic, but you clearly don’t need $A$: you could just as well have $S\to aB$ and do away with the second production. Your non-terminal $B$ doesn’t quite do what you want, however, since it can produce any non-empty string of $b$s; your grammar generates the language $\{ab^n:n\ge 1\}$. You need to make two modifications. First, you have to allow the grammar to generate the word $a$; this is most easily done as I did in my grammar for $(2)$. Secondly, you have to make sure that $B$ generates an *even* number of $b$s. If you have a more general definition of *regular grammar* than the one at the link above, you can do this with productions $B\to bbB\mid bb$. If not, you’ll need to introduce another non-terminal, say $X$, and have $B\to bX$ and two $X$ productions; can you figure out what they should be? I’ve left the answer in the spoiler-protected block below.

> $X\to bB\mid b$.

Comment: Okay, so the second iteration of 1 is correct. I understand why #2 is wrong now, thanks (that being because it's either $a^n$ power or $b^n$ power and never both). Oh and it'd be a single a|b because if it's $a^0$ or $b^0$ that'd just be equivalent to 1. Makes sense. For #3, could B also go to empty since it could be a 0? $ab^{2(0)} = a$  - Thanks for your help. I actually corrected 3 without editing it to here... I have close to the same for that one!

Comment: @Speakmore: You don’t need $B\to\lambda$ in $(3)$, because $A\to a$ takes care of that; you just need $B$ to generate everything of the form $b^{2n}$ with $n\ge 1$. Having $B\to\lambda$ as well doesn’t hurt anything, but it’s not necessary, and in some contexts it’s helpful not to have $\lambda$-productions if they can be avoided.

Comment: If I change it your notation of S→aB, wouldn't you need to account for B being equal to 1/nothing?

Comment: @Speakmore: In $(3)$? Yes. Sorry; I forgot that $A\to a$ was no longer there when I wrote the previous comment.